# Set a value runtime to combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a combobox populated with four items already. My app is receiving any of these four items on run time (one at a time). How can I set my comboBox with the received item (which is one of the four) on run time.

This is to make app a bit user friendly. So that user wouldnt have to select by himself. I know there can be other ways to do it but I want it to work like the way I explained in the first paragraph.

Also I have added this to make it uneditable.

```
comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

Comment: What have you currently done? Have you tried to bind your control's datasource to an observablecollection of your input items?

Comment: comboBox.SelectedItem = receivedItem;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no events fired when items are added to ComboBoxes. You are in control of when items are added, so when your code adds an item, it should fire it's own event.

However, if you know when you add the item, you can set it to equal the most recently added item like so:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.Count - 1;
```

or if you may be removing some items, like so:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
comboBox1.SelectedItem = item;
```